# How to print request string when ASIFormDataRequest failed?

Tags: iphone, xcode, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I am using ASIFormDataRequest asynchronously to get data from server.
When request failed for any reason then I want to save URL and requested string in database for further reference.

I am getting the URL from [request url] but how to get requested string from request.
Below code I am using.

```
 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [request setPostValue:requestString forKey:@"data"];

 [request setDelegate:self];

 [request startAsynchronous];

 //DELEGATE METHOD
 - (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
 {
     //PRINT REQUEST STRING WHEN FAILED
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can solve this using block:

     __block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url]; Courtesy: Bobj-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `[request setFailedBlock:^{...//print url...}];`